# KNOCKOUT - reuse jqm dialog to update different elements

Tags: dialog, knockout.js

i have this problem. I have a dialog running on jquery mobile. With this dialog i perform a search and if the search is successful with knockout i update my view-model. The problem is that i would reuse the dialog to update items that have same json structure but are placed in different position in my vm (in other words i would not create a specific function and specific search dialog for the same type of object but use always the same and at runtime update the correct/current item). My idea was to pass, when open dialog, the context of current elemet to update but i have no success in this.

Is this possible. What is the best practice to perform this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have made a custom binding for this, in combo with the native template binding of knockout you can get this behaviour, please see my bindings here

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings

Examples http://jsfiddle.net/H8xWY/7/

Code

```
<div id="dialog" data-bind="dialog: { autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: dialogTitle }, template: { name: 'dialog-template', data: dialogItem, 'if': dialogItem }, openDialog: dialogItem"></div>
```